# Is there any reason for using multiple VAOs in OpenGL 4.3 and higher?

Tags: opengl

Since in newer versions of OpenGL have option to create multiple attribute bindings within one VAO, is there any reason at all to use more than one VAO?

Comment: "*create multiple attribute bindings within one VAO*" Um... what does that mean? VAOs haven't changed very much since GL 3.0, and the primary change (separation of attribute formats from buffer bindings) isn't really that. Can you give more details about what you're talking about?

Comment: @NicolBolas isn't it that you can now use multiple buffer bind points within one VAO(by glVertexAttribBinding()), which can have unique attributes? Then you just bind the buffers to those buffer points(glVertexArrayVertexBuffer()). If I understand it corectly, using multiple buffer binding points gives similar effect to using multiple VAOs in previous openGL versions.

Comment: "*you can now use multiple buffer bind points within one VAO(by glVertexAttribBinding()), which can have unique attributes?*" ... you could *always* use multiple buffers with VAOs. Your attributes don't all have to come from the same buffer object; they *never* did. So it's unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: The main thing that separate attribute format does is make it so that you can change buffers without respecifying the format. So if you have a lot of geometry that uses the same vertex format, you can use the same VAO for them with only changes to the buffers between them.

Comment: I may have understood the documentation wrong, but aren't separate binding points for attributes like separate sets to add attributes to? and then you bind buffers to the binding point with suitable attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the separation of vertex formats from buffer bindings is to distinguish between the source in memory where various data comes from and the *interpretation* of that data. Buffers provide the storage; formats define the interpretation of that storage.

Separating these two concepts allow you to change storage without re-specifying the format. That is, you can use the same interpretation, just for a different set of data. If you have two character models that all have positions, normals, colors, texture coordinates, and skinning parameters, they use the same vertex format even if their data comes from different buffers. As such, they can share the same VAO, just with different buffers attached.

However, if you have two models with different vertex formats, you cannot do that. If one model doesn't have skinning parameters, or doesn't have per-vertex colors, or has some other information that the other model doesn't have, then they do not use compatible vertex formats. And thus, you'd have to specify different vertex formats in addition to different buffers. At which point, you may as well be using different VAOs, since you've had to specify all of the data again.